# What is a good approach to implement notifications across different apps?

Tags: node.js, rest, notifications

I'm working on a new startup, which is a social network. 
There will be 3 different apps (web app, android app and iphone app) that share the same back end:

I want to create a service to provide rest login, a second one  for core functionality (operations related to different users), and a third service to send notifications across users, for the 3 apps.

For example, an user logs into the web site, does some operation which requires to notify a second user, which should be able to see the notification trough both the mobile app, or the website.

Then, my question is, how can I implement this notification scheme? Do you know an example implementation I can start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't underestimate the complexity of this type of thing. That being said, Node.js gives you a number of advantages when it comes to accomplishing things like this, namely easier "push" functionality and operations that involve multiple users:

1. User A sends message to User B from his android phone
2. User A's app sends an http request to the backend stating that a new message has come in
3. The backend receives this request
4. The backend adds this message to the message table in the database
5. The backend checks if User B is logged in, and discovers User B has the iPhone app open

The apps will probably want to maintain some persistent connection with the backend, maybe long polling or something similar, which will allow the backend to send data whenever it has it using already-open connections

6. The backend sends  the message to User B through the persistent connection
7. User B's app sees the message and gives User B a notification
8. User B reads the message

Look at npm modules, which will cover a lot of this functionality for you.

Comment: What would be a good guide for this? I never implemented a solution of this kind. Were can I investigate this further? I don't know were to begin.

Comment: That's the usual problem with these sorts of projects. They're so big that it's hard to know where to start. If I were you, I would look into some terms. Node.js makes web apps really easy, with web frameworks like [express](https://codeforgeek.com/2014/06/express-nodejs-tutorial/), data storage in basically any database you want, caching and pub/sub communication (very helpful for this case) with [redis](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-redis-node-js/), client-side stuff with [angular](http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/09/28/angularjs-tutorial-for-beginners-with-nodejs-expressjs-and-mongodb/)...

Comment: There's also [handlebars](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/01/learn-handlebars-in-10-minutes/) and friends for templating, [passport](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619) for authentication, plenty of logging modules and basically anything else you could need. If there's any particular problem that you expect will take you over a few weeks to solve, and has been encountered by someone else before, there's probably an [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) module for it. Just pick a place to start and code.

Comment: I understand what you are exposing, but I would like to know what is a good pattern for implementing notifications. I would like to start by creating this rest service which will notify my users across differents applications.

Comment: The most complicated part is finding some way to send data to the client. There are a number of npm libraries which establish and maintain a persistent connection between the client (running any number of environments) and the node.js server. Once you have one of these set up, it's mostly plug and play, routing messages out as they come in, and saving copies for later viewing in the database. The process for this is described in the answer you just need the library